# Getting specific properties of custom object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a `CustomEvent` object that I need to retrieve specific properties for. This object is not a plain object, but rather is the result of `new CustomEvent();`. When I output this object in the [Chrome] browser console, I see the following:

```
CustomEvent{
   bubbles: false
   cancelBubble: false
   cancelable: false
   composed: false
   currentTarget: Window {...}
   defaultPrevented: false
   detail: {...}
   eventPhase: 0
   isTrusted: false
   path: [Window]
   returnValue: true
   srcElement: Window {...}
   target: Window {...}
   timeStamp: 4979.4150000670925
   type: "resize_element"
}
```

When I use `Object.keys(custom_event_obj)`, I get only one key, `isTrusted`. This would mean that `isTrusted` is the only enumerable key.

I use the following code to make sure:

```
for(var key_str in custom_event_obj)
{
   console.log(key_str, 'property is enumerable =', custom_event_obj.propertyIsEnumerable(key_str))
}
```

And I get the following result:

```
isTrusted is enumerable = true
detail is enumerable = false
initCustomEvent is enumerable = false
NONE is enumerable = false
CAPTURING_PHASE is enumerable = false
AT_TARGET is enumerable = false
BUBBLING_PHASE is enumerable = false
type is enumerable = false
target is enumerable = false
currentTarget is enumerable = false
eventPhase is enumerable = false
bubbles is enumerable = false
cancelable is enumerable = false
defaultPrevented is enumerable = false
composed is enumerable = false
timeStamp is enumerable = false
srcElement is enumerable = false
returnValue is enumerable = false
cancelBubble is enumerable = false
path is enumerable = false
composedPath is enumerable = false
stopPropagation is enumerable = false
stopImmediatePropagation is enumerable = false
preventDefault is enumerable = false
initEvent is enumerable = false
```

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` gives me only one key as well: `isTrusted`.

This list contains keys that don't appear in the browser console result.

I'd like to get just the keys that appear in the browser console. How do I filter those keys out from the full list above?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm having the same issue with unit tests in Jest, I want to see the data, I don't care about that flag but that is all I get, same as you. So any solution?

Comment: @ghiscoding Not really. I decided to use `for...in` and capture values from all keys that are not capitalized, effectively creating a plain object in the process.

Answer (score 0):

> *Object.getOwnPropertyNames gives me only one key as well: isTrusted.*

Not for me:

```js
let CustomEvent = {
   bubbles: false,
   cancelBubble: false,
   cancelable: false,
   composed: false,
   currentTarget: null,
   defaultPrevented: false,
   detail: null,
   eventPhase: 0,
   isTrusted: false,
   path: [],
   returnValue: true,
   srcElement: null,
   target: null,
   timeStamp: 4979.4150000670925,
   type: "resize_element"
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(CustomEvent));
```

But, while that does get you the property names, you'll still have to loop over the object and get the values for the properties.

You can also use [`.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to only enumerate the properties that are not inherited.

```js
let CustomEvent = {
   bubbles: false,
   cancelBubble: false,
   cancelable: false,
   composed: false,
   currentTarget: null,
   defaultPrevented: false,
   detail: null,
   eventPhase: 0,
   isTrusted: false,
   path: [],
   returnValue: true,
   srcElement: null,
   target: null,
   timeStamp: 4979.4150000670925,
   type: "resize_element"
}

for(var prop in CustomEvent){
  if(CustomEvent.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    console.log(prop,  CustomEvent[prop]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Result I get is `isTrusted false`. Same as before.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill You are using the exact same code as I have here?

Comment: The thing is you're creating a plain object, when I mentioned CustomEvent. Create the object like this instead:  `var test_custom_event_obj = new CustomEvent('test_event', {detail: {'one': 'first'}});`